# facebook messenger and dialogflow:: detect each event individually from multiple generic templates button

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-messenger

I am working with `chatbot` and `dialogflow` is my nlp platform. Currently, I am using generic templates to show my products on messenger.

Now, when customer clicks on `buy now` button from multiple templates buttons I want to detect which template **`button`** has been clicked  (detect individual event) and want to set different message for different product from **dialogflow**.

One way to do the job  is using `context` but I want to know whether it is possible to achieve the same outcome without using `context` or not?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a [`postback button`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/postback)?

Comment: Not yet, thinking of using postback button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the payload field in the [`postback button`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/postback) to send a specific message back to dialogflow when the button is clicked.

If you combine this with the parameters, you can use them to trigger specific intents, or just to send the information of the product clicked. For example:

Imagine an intent with the following phrases:

[image: Training phrases]

In this case: "toaster" and "microwave" are part of an entity called objects

[image: Parameters]

In the response to messenger, you can include reference to this parameter, for example:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "payload": "trigger buy $objects",
            "title": "Buy Now",
            "type": "postback"
          }
        ],
        "text": "Buy the $objects!"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which will show the parameter:

[image: Messenger example]

When the user clicks on the button, messenger will send dialogflow the content of the payload, in this case: "trigger buy toaster". Note that in the payload the reference `$objects` is also replaced by the actual parameter "toaster".

So you can create a new intent in Dialogflow with training phrases as "trigger buy toaster" to catch these actions with the object that is going to be purchased.

You can also use the webhook fulfillment to add more logic to the generation of the `postback button` responses and to the intent that receives the answer.

Comment: But at first i want to display all of my products, e.g if someone say "products" i will display all the products microwave, toaster, grinder which will have two postback buttons suppose, buy now, details. how can i do that any idea?

Comment: You can continue using the Generic template as you intended. In the buttons, just use `postback buttons`. See [this example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/templates/generic#button). If you are showing all your products at once, it's easier because you don't have to use the parameters as variables in your rich response, you can simply go ahead and create a rich response with those values. For example, in the payloads, instead of being `"payload": "trigger buy $objects"` you can simply put `"payload": "trigger buy toaster"` or the products you want to show

Comment: thank you so much! this is what i wanted and it worked!