# How to catch Facebook Card Response button click event in Dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have connected Dialogflow agent to a Facebook page, and i'm displaying Facebook card response using the fulfillment feature in Dialogflow. i can't figure out how to catch the card button click event. I need the chat to move to the next intent on button click. However button click doesn't trigger anything.

Here's the fulfillment code used to create button

```
function getState(agent){
state = agent.parameters.State;  
    return getAd()
    .then(result => {
     for(const item of result.result){
        agent.add(new Card({
         title: item.nmi,
         imageUrl: 'url',
         text: item.structuredAddress.singleAddressLine,
         buttonText: item.nmi,
         buttonUrl: 'uri'
      })
      );
    }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      agent.add(`I'm sorry.`);
    });
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the payload field in the postback button to send a
> specific message back to dialogflow when the button is clicked.
>
> If you combine this with the parameters, you can use them to trigger
> specific intents, or just to send the information of the product
> clicked

check the original answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858414/facebook-messenger-and-dialogflow-detect-each-event-individually-from-multiple)